# What does “do“ mean in old cocktails?

Tags: cocktails, recipes

**What does “do“ mean in  old cocktails?**

There’s a post on ***“do”*** in old recipes of
[Seasoned Advice SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36044/what-does-do-mean-in-old-recipes).

It says that “do.” should be read as “ditto” which makes sense, but I’m reading “Jerry Thomas Bartenders Guide How to mix drinks, or poison customers in the name of Lucifer.” and I found this recipe:

2 glasses of maraschino

2 do. do. Curaçoa

Fill the bowl with ripe strawberries. Should the strawberrry season be over, or under, add a few drops of extract of peach or vanilla.

How do I interpret “do. do.”? In some of the other recipes interpreting “do.” as ditto makes sense. The book was written in 1862.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In some of the other recipes interpreting “do.” as ditto makes sense.

It makes sense here too:

- 2
- ditto the "glasses"
- ditto the "of"
- Curaçao

Comment: That makes sense, I’ll give the recipe a try. Thank you!